# Automatic scrolling scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a question. I want to display the user some content in a `UIScrollView`. I want to `autoscroll` the `UIScrollView` fast from bottom to top (like in the apple stores `iPad`). I tried to use `DDAutoscrollview` (If someone knows), but it doesn't work for me. Do have someone a solution for me to `autoscroll` a `UIScrollView`? Any code snippets would be nice.

#### .h

```
@interface Interface1 : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UILabel *warnung;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
```

#### .m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 
                                       self.scrollView.contentSize.height - 
                                         self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];

    CGPoint newOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    newOffset.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {        
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 420)];    
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Thanks.

---

#### > THUMBS UP FOR THE AWNSER THAT WAS GIVEN BY TOBI!!!

---

Comment: How about [self.scrollView setScrollsToTop:YES]; in whichever method you wanted this to happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `setContentOffset:animated:`

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = ...;
CGPoint newOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
newOffset.y = 0;
[scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

**Edit:**

To use it like some kind of start animation you could do this in the scrollView's view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGPoint newOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    newOffset.y = 0;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
}
```

**Edit 2 / 3:**

To make the scrolling happen slower, use this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    float scrollDuration = 4.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:scrollDuration animations:^{
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Well that depends on when you want the scrolling to happen :)

Comment: actually I could put the code in viewdidappear? what do u mean?

Comment: Do I have to replace the height with the height of the scrollview?

Comment: the code assumes that your view controller has a property `scrollView`. If your's don't, you have to replace every `self.scrollView` in my example with a valid reference to your scrollView

Comment: do you get a compiler error, or does the animation not work as you want?

Comment: Ohh I forgot to say...I'm using storyboards and arc! Maybe this could be a problem?

Comment: and are you able to scroll the scrollView "manually" by dragging?

Comment: nope autolayout disabled but on my simulator it doesnt work at all just on my device it works fine (not the atutoscroll) just the srollview

Comment: did you set the `contentSize` of your scrollView?

Comment: you have to replace `self.scrollView` in your code with `self.scroller`.

Comment: do you want the up-scrolling to happen **later** or **slower**?

Comment: slower...yes just slower later actually doesnt matter

Comment: that's a bit more complicated. I'll update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you...You saved my life twice... hahhahaha :D

Comment: I think thats the longest comment compilation on stackoverflow ever :D

Comment: ...theres one thing...If the view loads the scrollview is n top. Then it springs on bottom and animate to top is there a programmiticaly way to disable this or should I replace the scrollview in the storyboard...means that I replace the content, that the buttom is shown if the view loads...

Comment: jesus man you're better than steve jobs or the whole apple programmers on the dev. forum...they even dont help you...sad...(cry, cry) f***ing egoists! Hate those..But still luv you :D

Comment: done. just move the code to scroll the scrollView to bottom in the `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: I would be glad if you could help me with ths too see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273435/automatic-paging-scrollview