# Automatic paging scrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a question. I want to display the user some content in a scrollview. I want to autoscroll the scrollview fast from left to right. I tried to use DDAutoscrollview (If someone knows), but it doesnt work for me. Do have someone a solution for me to autoscroll a Uiscrollview horizontaly? I've settet up a pagecontrol for the scrollview, because it uses paging. Any code snippets would be nice.

My code (Just of the Scrollview):

.h

```
    @interface Interface1 : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;


}
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, 230)];

        [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm using Storyboards and ARC.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use any extra libraries for this. UIScrollView has a `contentOffset` property on which you can simply set the animated flag to YES:

```
[myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
```

Or you could wrap it in a UIView animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
    [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:NO];
}];
```

Either way, you'll probably want to set the contentSize of the scroll view to at least 640 wide so you can actually page.

Comment: I simply want that the scrollview pages to right, if the user loads the view

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated`. It will allow you to give it a rect inside your contentSize and it will scroll to it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how fast exactly but have you tried this method?

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
// In your case, e.g.:
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(640, 0) animated:YES]
```