# How to change to another image every 5 seconds in UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, nstimer

I have a banner currently that gets images from my site, and I can scroll the banners left and rights to get the next or previous image. However, I also want it to change the images automatically every 5 secs.

I tried adding these codes to imageView, but the banner becomes empty not showing any images.

```
imageView.animateImages = delegate.bannerDetailsArray;
imageView.animationDuration = 5.0;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

I am guessing that the array is where the issue is, but I am currently no clue how to fix it.

Can anyone shred some lights how to make the banner images change every 5 seconds?

```
-(void) bannerSettings
{
bannerScrollView = [UIScrollView new];
[bannerScrollView setBackgroundColor:BackGroundColor];
[bannerScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,delegate.windowWidth, [self     imageWithImage:delegate.windowWidth maxHeight:200])];
[bannerScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[bannerScrollView   setContentSize:CGSizeMake([delegate.bannerDetailsArray count]*delegate.windowWidth, 0)];

NSLog(@"%@",delegate.bannerDetailsArray);

for(int i=0;i<[delegate.bannerDetailsArray count];i++)
{
    UIImageView * imageView = [UIImageView new];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(i*delegate.windowWidth,0,delegate.windowWidth,[self imageWithImage:delegate.windowWidth maxHeight:200])];
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[delegate.bannerDetailsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"bannerImage"]]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [imageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imageView setTag:i];

    //imageView.animateImages = delegate.bannerDetailsArray;
    //imageView.animationDuration = 3.0;
    //imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    //[imageview startAnimating];


    [bannerScrollView addSubview:imageView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bannerGestureTapped:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

*The above codes works fine when the animation part ignored. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView has a property

```
 setContentOffset:animated:
```

Use this property in NSTimer function to see the effect.Follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13258938/automatic-scrolling-scrollview). It contains step by step process of how to make this.

**Or.**

You can use UIPageViewController and NStimer combination like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668536/uipageviewcontroller-automatic-scrolling-in-ios) popular thread.

UIPageVC has a method like this.

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
                 direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction
                  animated:(BOOL)animated
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

It expects a data to deliver. Then you can use NSTimer for a certain period of time to give the image.

Comment: Thank you. I have kind of make it working now. I added a NStimer to the imageView and it now fires once every 5 seconds.